# Python project little issue I can't seem to figure out to print something

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib

So, I've recently been adventuring around with python, and I've been attempting to learn a bit of things by mixing code that I find and making it into something I could end up using in the future. I've almost completely the project, although when I print out the links, it says

https://v3rmillion.net/showthread.php

Instead of being something like that I would prefer being:

https://v3rmillion.net/showthread.php?tid=393794

```
import requests,os,urllib,sys, webbrowser, bs4

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def startup():
    os.system('cls')
    print('Discord To Profile')
    user = raw_input('Discord Tag: ')
    r = requests.get('https://www.google.ca/search?source=hp&q=' + user + ' site:v3rmillion.net')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    print soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text

    #This part below is where I'm having the issue.
    content=r.content.decode('UTF-8','replace')
    links=[]
    while '<h3 class="r">' in content:
        content=content.split('<h3 class="r">', 1)[1]
        split_content=content.split('</h3>', 1)
        link='http'+split_content[1].split(':http',1)[1].split('%',1)[0]
        links.append(link)
        #content=split_content[1]
    for link in links[:5]:
        print(link)

startup()
```

Comment: So what's your _question_?  Please [edit] your post to show what you want in the question itself.  Even if people are willing to enable JavaScript from some random site just to figure out what you're asking (I'm not), the resulting Q&A will be worthless to anyone who comes along after links have rotted away.

Comment: it shows https://v3rmillion.net/showthread.php
When it simply should only be showing https://v3rmillion.net/showthread.php?tid=393794

Comment: external links are bad, mkay

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the results coming back from your code, and I think you can substantially reduce your code by looking for the `<cite>` tags:

```
def startup():
    os.system('cls')
    print('Discord To Profile')
    user = raw_input('Discord Tag: ')
    r = requests.get('https://www.google.ca/search?source=hp&q=' + user + ' site:v3rmillion.net')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    links=[]
    for link in soup.find_all('cite'):
        links.append(link.string)
    for link in links[:5]:
        print(link)
```