# Python BeautifulSoup HTML Scraping Issue

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

So, I've recently been playing around with python, and I've been trying to learn a bit of newer things by mixing some code that I find and making it into something I could possibly end up using in the future. Today, I've almost completely the project, although when I print out the links, it says

https://v3rmillion.net/showthread.php

Instead of being something like that I would prefer being:

https://v3rmillion.net/showthread.php?tid=393794

```
import requests,os,urllib,sys, webbrowser, bs4

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def startup():
    os.system('cls')
    print('Discord To Profile')
    user = raw_input('Discord Tag: ')
    r = requests.get('https://www.google.ca/search?source=hp&q=' + user + ' site:v3rmillion.net')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    print soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text
    content=r.content.decode('UTF-8','replace')

    #Attempting to scrape links, although I'd like the full length instead of just .php
    links=[]
    while '<h3 class="r">' in content:
        content=content.split('<h3 class="r">', 1)[1]
        split_content=content.split('</h3>', 1)
        link='http'+split_content[1].split(':http',1)[1].split('%',1)[0]
        links.append(link)
        content=split_content[1]
    for link in links[:5]:  # max number of links 5
        print(link)

startup()
```

Comment: How is this question different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162774/python-project-little-issue-i-cant-seem-to-figure-out-to-print-something) ??

Comment: why are you searching in google, when you can directly state the url you want, and change its id as needed with `raw_input`.

Comment: I have answered the question on the first version of the question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162774/python-project-little-issue-i-cant-seem-to-figure-out-to-print-something> and I'll flag this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python project little issue I can't seem to figure out to print something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162774/python-project-little-issue-i-cant-seem-to-figure-out-to-print-something)